# Why parallel qsort in clojure slow than implementation of common?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming

I'm writing a parallel qsort algorithm, but he working slow than common implementation.
I think the problem is in function 'concat'. How to speed up the algorithm?

```
(defn qsort-orig [L]
  (if  (empty? L)
    '()
    (let [[pivot & l] L]
      (concat (qsort-orig (for [y l :when (<  y pivot)] y))
              (list pivot)
              (qsort-orig (for [y l :when (>= y pivot)] y))))))

(defn qsort [L]  
(if (empty? L)
  '()
  (let [ [pivot & l] L 
        Left  (for [y l :when (<  y pivot)] y)
        Right (for [y l :when (>= y pivot)] y)]
    (concat (apply concat (pmap qsort 
                            (if (list? Left) 
                              Left 
                              (list Left))))
            (list pivot)
            (apply concat (pmap qsort 
                            (if (list? Right) 
                              Right 
                              (list Right))))))))
# for test
(time (qsort (repeatedly 10000 #(rand-int 10000))))
(time (qsort-orig (repeatedly 10000 #(rand-int 10000))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the memory allocation times for both of these are washing out the real time differences between them.

- if you use `recur` in `qsort-orig` then it wont blow the stack as quickly and should run a lot faster because it will spend less time allocating memory.
- the use of apply and concat allocates will make one long sequence for each of the calls on left and right as it builds the call to concat which will require allocating memory for each call
- pmap allocates a small structure (a future call) for each entry in the array.